# Display custom Map route on MapControl Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I can find route between two points using

```
MapRouteFinderResult routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(startPoint,endPoint,MapRouteOptimization.Time,MapRouteRestrictions.None,290);
MapRouteView viewOfRoute = new MapRouteView(routeResult.Route);
```

What I want to do is create a `Route` object with my own waypoints, instead of giving the task to phone. One option is create a SVG myself and overlay it on Map
How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness this is how you do it. A tidier way can be used but my example is to show the methodology. (Windows Phone 8.1)

```
BasicGeoposition waypoint1 = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = lat1, Longitude = long1 };
BasicGeoposition waypoint2 = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = lat2, Longitude = long2 };
BasicGeoposition waypoint3 = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = lat3, Longitude = long3 };

List<Geopoint> positions = new List<Geopoint>();

positions.Add(new Geopoint(waypoint1));
positions.Add(new Geopoint(waypoint2));
positions.Add(new Geopoint(waypoint3));

// Get the route between the points.
MapRouteFinderResult routeResult = await MapRouteFinder.GetWalkingRouteFromWaypointsAsync(positions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the waypoints of the custom route? If so, you could simply draw it using a [MapPolyline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mappolyline.aspx). (Set the [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mappolyline.path.aspx) property to a list of custom waypoints.)